# Can't boot into Ubuntu 16.04 after installing Ubuntu 18.04 (on separate partition)

Tags: linux, ubuntu, boot, grub2

I have a multiboot system with two hard disks:

- Windows and some old Ubuntu versions on /dev/sda
- Ubuntu 16.04 on /dev/sdb1

Then I installed Ubuntu 18.04 on the empty partition /dev/sdb2. I didn't remember where the old boot loader was located, so I chose /dev/sdb for the new bootloader.

Now I can boot Ubuntu 18.04 without problems but when I boot Ubuntu 16.04, I get this:

```
[   1.820371] [drm:intel_set_pch_fifo_underrun_reporting [i915]] *ERROR* uncleared pch fifo underrun on pch transcoder A
[   1.820395] [drm:intel_pch_fifo_underrun_irq_handler [i915]]  *ERROR* PCH transcoder A FIFO underrun
[   2.023723] usb 2-1.6: string descriptor 0 read error: -22
ssd1: clean, ... files, ... blocks
[   5.074685] usb 2-1.6: string descriptor 0 read error: -22
Welcome to emergency mode! After logging in, ...
```

I already have tried logging in into rescue mode and running **sudo fsck -f /dev/sdb1**, but without success.

How can I repair this?

EDIT:

My boot.log:

```
$ cat boot.log
[  OK  ] Started Show Plymouth Boot Screen.
[  OK  ] Mounted /media/ssd3.
[  OK  ] Started Forward Password Requests to Plymouth Directory Watch.
[  OK  ] Started Braille Device Support.
[  OK  ] Found device ST9500325AS 6.
[  OK  ] Found device ST9500325AS 7.
[  OK  ] Found device ST9500325AS 5.
[  OK  ] Found device ST9500325AS Acer.
         Mounting /media/C...
         Activating swap /dev/disk/by-uuid/d7c7e54d-0eb9-49e9-bdba-de11b5637723...
         Starting File System Check on /dev/disk/by-uuid/425e03d0-535c-4c23-9570-b7a03afc2b39...
         Starting File System Check on /dev/disk/by-uuid/99158754-acff-4379-9640-1adc6edb157e...
[  OK  ] Activated swap /dev/disk/by-uuid/d7c7e54d-0eb9-49e9-bdba-de11b5637723.
[  OK  ] Reached target Swap.
[  OK  ] Found device ST9500325AS Daten.
         Mounting /media/E...
[  OK  ] Started File System Check on /dev/disk/by-uuid/425e03d0-535c-4c23-9570-b7a03afc2b39.
         Mounting /media/ubuntu1210...
[  OK  ] Found device ST9500325AS shared.
         Starting File System Check on /dev/disk/by-uuid/661027b0-7fb9-4e5b-bc30-4bdf232eda36...
[  OK  ] Mounted /media/ubuntu1210.
[  OK  ] Started File System Check on /dev/disk/by-uuid/99158754-acff-4379-9640-1adc6edb157e.
         Mounting /media/ubuntu1404...
[  OK  ] Mounted /media/ubuntu1404.
[  OK  ] Mounted /media/C.
[  OK  ] Mounted /media/E.
[  OK  ] Started File System Check on /dev/disk/by-uuid/661027b0-7fb9-4e5b-bc30-4bdf232eda36.
         Mounting /media/shared...
[  OK  ] Mounted /media/shared.
[ TIME ] Timed out waiting for device dev-disk-by\x2duuid-57f163ae\x2d54d6\x2d4c56\x2db5c7\x2d84e1d5e4b438.device.
[DEPEND] Dependency failed for File System Check on /dev/disk/by-uuid/57f163ae-54d6-4c56-b5c7-84e1d5e4b438.
[DEPEND] Dependency failed for /media/ssd2.
[DEPEND] Dependency failed for Local File Systems.
[DEPEND] Dependency failed for Clean up any mess left by 0dns-up.
         Starting Set console font and keymap...
         Starting Enable support for additional executable binary formats...
[  OK  ] Stopped Clean PHP session files every 30 mins.
[  OK  ] Stopped target Graphical Interface.
[  OK  ] Stopped Accounts Service.
[  OK  ] Started Stop ureadahead data collection 45s after completed startup.
[  OK  ] Closed UUID daemon activation socket.
[  OK  ] Stopped Getty on tty1.
[  OK  ] Stopped getty on tty2-tty6 if dbus and logind are not available.
[  OK  ] Stopped Daily apt upgrade and clean activities.
[  OK  ] Stopped Daily apt download activities.
[  OK  ] Stopped Bluetooth service.
[  OK  ] Reached target Bluetooth.
[  OK  ] Stopped Save/Restore Sound Card State.
[  OK  ] Stopped Manage Sound Card State (restore and store).
[  OK  ] Stopped ACPI Events Check.
[  OK  ] Stopped Light Display Manager.
[  OK  ] Stopped Detect the available GPUs and deal with any system changes.
[  OK  ] Stopped Daily Cleanup of Temporary Directories.
[  OK  ] Stopped Timer to automatically fetch and run repair assertions.
[  OK  ] Reached target Timers.
[  OK  ] Stopped IIO Sensor Proxy service.
[  OK  ] Closed Unix socket for apport crash forwarding.
[  OK  ] Closed ACPID Listen Socket.
[  OK  ] Stopped target Multi-User System.
[  OK  ] Stopped LSB: Speech Dispatcher.
[  OK  ] Stopped Make remote CUPS printers available locally.
[  OK  ] Stopped CUPS Scheduler.
[  OK  ] Closed CUPS Scheduler.
[  OK  ] Stopped LSB: Set the CPU Frequency Scaling governor to "ondemand".
[  OK  ] Stopped Modem Manager.
[  OK  ] Stopped Cgroup management proxy.
[  OK  ] Stopped Restore /etc/resolv.conf if the system crashed before the ppp link was shut down.
[  OK  ] Stopped Initialize hardware monitoring sensors.
[  OK  ] Stopped LSB: Start xrdp and sesman daemons.
[  OK  ] Stopped Login Service.
[  OK  ] Stopped TeamViewer remote control daemon.
[  OK  ] Stopped Network Manager Wait Online.
[  OK  ] Stopped crash report submission daemon.
[  OK  ] Stopped LSB: automatic crash report generation.
[  OK  ] Stopped The PHP 7.0 FastCGI Process Manager.
[  OK  ] Stopped Auto import assertions from block devices.
[  OK  ] Stopped Avahi mDNS/DNS-SD Stack.
[  OK  ] Stopped LSB: Apache2 web server.
[  OK  ] Stopped Regular background program processing daemon.
[  OK  ] Stopped Network Manager.
[  OK  ] Stopped LSB: Record successful boot for GRUB.
[  OK  ] Stopped Hold until boot process finishes up.
[  OK  ] Stopped /etc/rc.local Compatibility.
[  OK  ] Stopped Permit User Sessions.
         Starting Set console scheme...
[  OK  ] Stopped Snappy daemon.
[  OK  ] Closed Socket activation for snappy daemon.
[  OK  ] Stopped CUPS Scheduler.
[  OK  ] Stopped Automatically repair incorrect owner/permissions on core devices.
[  OK  ] Stopped Unattended Upgrades Shutdown.
[  OK  ] Stopped LSB: daemon to balance interrupts for SMP systems.
[  OK  ] Stopped MySQL Community Server.
[  OK  ] Stopped System Logging Service.
[  OK  ] Closed Syslog Socket.
[  OK  ] Stopped Run anacron jobs.
[  OK  ] Stopped D-Bus System Message Bus.
[  OK  ] Reached target Login Prompts.
[  OK  ] Stopped Cgroup management daemon.
[  OK  ] Closed Avahi mDNS/DNS-SD Stack Activation Socket.
[  OK  ] Stopped Thermal Daemon Service.
[  OK  ] Stopped target Basic System.
[  OK  ] Reached target Paths.
[  OK  ] Closed D-Bus System Message Bus Socket.
[  OK  ] Reached target Sockets.
[  OK  ] Stopped target System Initialization.
[  OK  ] Started Emergency Shell.
[  OK  ] Reached target Emergency Mode.
         Starting Create Volatile Files and Directories...
         Starting LSB: AppArmor initialization...
         Starting Tell Plymouth To Write Out Runtime Data...
         Starting Nameserver information manager...
[  OK  ] Started Set console scheme.
[  OK  ] Started Nameserver information manager.
[  OK  ] Started Create Volatile Files and Directories.
[  OK  ] Started Tell Plymouth To Write Out Runtime Data.
         Starting Network Time Synchronization...
         Starting Update UTMP about System Boot/Shutdown...
[  OK  ] Reached target Network (Pre).
         Mounting Arbitrary Executable File Formats File System...
[  OK  ] Started Set console font and keymap.
[  OK  ] Mounted Arbitrary Executable File Formats File System.
[  OK  ] Started Network Time Synchronization.
[  OK  ] Started Update UTMP about System Boot/Shutdown.
[  OK  ] Started Enable support for additional executable binary formats.
         Starting Update UTMP about System Runlevel Changes...
[  OK  ] Reached target System Time Synchronized.
[  OK  ] Created slice system-getty.slice.
[  OK  ] Started Update UTMP about System Runlevel Changes.
[  OK  ] Started LSB: AppArmor initialization.
         Starting Raise network interfaces...
[  OK  ] Started Raise network interfaces.
[  OK  ] Reached target Network.
[  OK  ] Reached target Network is Online.
```

Since I'm trying to load the same OS on the same hardware as before, I think my problem is about the new GRUB version or configuration.

Menu entry for Ubuntu 16.04 in Ubuntu 16.04 installation (/boot/grub/grub.cfg):

```
menuentry 'Ubuntu' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-simple-8276f4fe-1bcd-4d25-8d6d-874f8e69a9b7' {
    recordfail
    load_video
    gfxmode $linux_gfx_mode
    insmod gzio
    if [ x$grub_platform = xxen ]; then insmod xzio; insmod lzopio; fi
    insmod part_msdos
    insmod ext2
    set root='hd1,msdos1'
    if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd1,msdos1 --hint-efi=hd1,msdos1 --hint-baremetal=ahci1,msdos1  8276f4fe-1bcd-4d25-8d6d-874f8e69a9b7
    else
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 8276f4fe-1bcd-4d25-8d6d-874f8e69a9b7
    fi
        linux   /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-121-generic root=UUID=8276f4fe-1bcd-4d25-8d6d-874f8e69a9b7 ro  quiet splash $vt_handoff
    initrd  /boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-121-generic
}
```

Menu entry for Ubuntu 16.04 in Ubuntu 18.04 installation (/boot/grub/grub.cfg):

```
menuentry 'Ubuntu 16.04.4 LTS (16.04) (auf /dev/sdb1)' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'osprober-gnulinux-simple-8276f4fe-1bcd-4d25-8d6d-874f8e69a9b7' {
    insmod part_msdos
    insmod ext2
    set root='hd1,msdos1'
    if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd1,msdos1 --hint-efi=hd1,msdos1 --hint-baremetal=ahci1,msdos1  8276f4fe-1bcd-4d25-8d6d-874f8e69a9b7
    else
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 8276f4fe-1bcd-4d25-8d6d-874f8e69a9b7
    fi
    linux /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-121-generic root=UUID=8276f4fe-1bcd-4d25-8d6d-874f8e69a9b7 ro quiet splash $vt_handoff
    initrd /boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-121-generic
}
```

Comment: If you can, don’t use DisplayPort. IIRC this is a long-standing bug that hasn’t been resolved. It only happens when using DisplayPort.

Comment: I don't have DisplayPort. I only have HDMI connected. Unplugging my second screen doesn't help.

Comment: Hm, it’s probably a different issue then, sorry. It’s caused by the Intel graphics driver. In my case, it caused the display data stream to cease in a way that made even the display crash. Are you planning to use GPU-intensive applications on Linux?

Comment: No. Can I unload the Intel graphics driver?

Comment: I think the title is misleading: I don't see a relation between the graphic card warning and the aborted boot

Comment: So do you think it's about the USB error?

Comment: Okay, I changed the title.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that **/dev/sdb2** was formatted during the installation of Ubuntu 18.04. So its UUID has changed and **/etc/fstab** wasn't correct anymore.

I had to boot Ubuntu 18.04, to mount **/dev/sdb2** and to update its UUID in **/etc/fstab** (of the mounted partition).

The UUID can be retrieved via **sudo blkid**.

Answer (score 0):

Guess: Ubuntu 18.04 has kernel drivers that set up the hardware in certain ways which the kernel drivers in Ubunutu 16.04 don't understand, or don't take into account during initialition. So if you warm-boot Ubuntu 16.04 after booting Ubuntu 18.04, same basic hardware doesn't act as expected, leading to those errors.

Diagnose: Cold boot Ubuntu 16.04 (shut the computer off, cut power for a few seconds), and see if the problem still happens.

Workaround: Always cold boot Ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: Good hint! When I cold boot Ubuntu 16.04, it gets further than before. But it still ends with "Welcome to emergency mode". Can I manually remove some kernel drivers in GRUB?